# Is there a way to get a variable from the scope where a function is executed?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have this function

```js
function send(msg, channel = message.channel) {
    channel.send(msg)
}
```

If I run it, I get the error "message is not defined".
Can I get the value of **message** from the scope where the function is executed, without passing it?

Comment: Nope, you should pass it.